# Generic networking decoding with Codable & JSONParser

Tags: ios, swift, generics, codable, jsondecoder

i have 2 main parts in my app infrastructure.

```
NetworkingManager
NetworkRequest
```

My goal is to have the request hold its `Codable` `Type` so when networking is done the `Manager` layer can instantiate new instance with the correct type by using

`decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable`

so my `NetworkRequest` look like so

```
class NetworkRequest {
  var objectClass:Codable.Type
}
```

lets say i have a `Person` class which conforms to `Codable`

```
class Person : Codable {
 var name:String?
}
```

now i need to assign the type into the request like so (in an ugly way to get to the point here)

```
let request = NetworkingRequest()
request.objectClass = Person.self
```

now when i want the `NetworkingManager` to decode the response i use it like so:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(type:request.objectClass, data:dataFromService)
```

the problem is when i do so i get this error:

Cannot invoke decode with an argument list of type (Decodable.Type, from: Data). Expected an argument list of type (T.Type, from: Data).

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class NetworkRequest<T: Codable> {
    var objectClass: T.Type!

    init(objectClass : T.Type) {
        self.objectClass = objectClass
    }

}

class Person : Codable {
    var name:String?
}

let request = NetworkRequest<Person>(objectClass: Person.self)

let response : Dictionary<String,Any> = ["name":"test"]
let data : Data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: response,options: [])

do {
    let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(request.objectClass, from: data)
    print(person.name ?? "--")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
class NetworkRequest<T: Codable> {
    var objectClass: T.Type

    init(objectClass: T.Type) {
        self.objectClass = objectClass
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does marking `NetworkRequest` as a genric `<T: Codeable>` do what you need?

```
class NetworkRequest<T: Codable> {
    var objectClass: T.Type
}
```

Then initing and calling like

```
let request = NetworkRequest<Person>()
request.objectClass = Person.self
```

And calling

```
try JSONDecoder().decode(request.objectClass, from: dataFromService)
```

Comment: Im trying to wrap my networking manager so it can handle generic requests.
it has a func doNetworking(request:NetworkRequest){
}

but when i do so i must provide explicit type, by doing so i can use the generic type